# Does Flutter render with Skia also on iOS?

Tags: flutter

According to Skia's homepage **Android**, Google Chrome, Chrome OS, ... are supported by Skia. There is no reference that iOS is supported by Skia's engine.

**Question**

But in another article it is described that elements are purely drawn with Skia. 
So how does it work on iOS?

> and draws it on a Skia canvas, instead of using the native UI elements

(https://xamarinhelp.com/flutter-xamarins-next-big-competitor/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Flutter renders with Skia also on iOS.
Skia is written in C and that can usually be compiled for any platform. Skia also addresses graphics hardware directly and therefore doesn't depend that much on the target platform.

Comment: Mostly C++ (about 70%)

Answer (score 3):

Skia "serves as the graphics engine for Google Chrome and Chrome OS, Android, " Firefox, Flutter, Fuchsia, and others.

That just means that Skia is used by those products.  Skia is currently actively tested on Linux, Windows, MacOS, ChromeOS, Android, and iOS.